# connecting to a webservice from android - AsyncTask or Service?

Tags: android, web-services, service, android-asynctask

I'm writing an android app that will connect to a REST/JSON webservice.  Users will be retrieving information, uploading comments, downloading and uploading images etc.

I know that I shouldn't keep all this network communication in the Activity/UI thread, as it will cause ANRs.  What I'm confused about is whether I should use an AsyncTask or a Service with "manual" threading to accomplish this;

With a Service, I'd simply have a public method for each method in the webservice's API.  I'd then implement threading within each of these methods.

If I used an AsyncTask, I would create a helper class that defined AsyncTasks for each method in the webservice's API.

Which method is preferred?  Interaction with the webservice will only happen while the user is in the Activity.  Once they switch to another application, or exit the program, there is no need for communication with the webservice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you go for the AsyncTask solution. It is an easy and straightforward way of running requests or any other background tasks of the UI-thread.

It's also easy to implement e.g. onProgressUpdate if you need to show a progress bar of some sort while running your requests.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation.  However, after watching this google IO video (http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html), I decided to go for a service based approach.  I may still use AsyncTasks for instances where the user will require immediate feedback from the service (posting a comment for example).  For simple background tasks, it seems like AsyncTask is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `IntentService`, it is not much more complex to implement and is definitely more robust because it is not tied so closely on the ActivityLifecycle (in particular to `onConfigurationChange()`)

Answer (score 0):

This library provides an async wrapper to Apache httpclient available in Android.

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/